# How to cancel vscode extention update?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on a C++ project(on remote) so I heavily rely on C/C++ extension.
Recently they probably released some new component for the extension.
This triggered auto update but the Downloading stucked.
[image]

Now my C/C++ is useless.
I've tried disable/enable, uninstall/install, even rebooting the computer.
None worked.
So how can I cancel this update and get my extension back.

I've switched off extension auto-update so this won't happen again.

Comment: just download the version of the extension you want from the marker place, and use the top menu on the Extension bar: `Install from VSIX`

Comment: @rioV8 your comment seems to be the only way

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know there's no way currently to cancel an extension upgrade...
rather you can downgrade it and stop the extensions update
[This](https://tpodolak.com/blog/2017/04/09/downgrading-visual-studio-code-extension/) would be helpful for downgrading

Comment: It doesn't work. When I enabled the extension again, the downloading returned.

Comment: https://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W426 try this